# PYODBC error 07002 - Too few parameters

Tags: python, sql, database, ms-access, pyodbc

Put simply, this code takes a quantity of a stock item,and updates the value by adding a number from one of the GUI elements. Whenever I try to run the code below:

```
Change = self.ui.Modify_Stock_Screen_Change.text()
Change = int(Change)
DBConnect = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=H:\\Computer Science\\X\\Y\\Z\\Database.accdb;')
DBSelect = DBConnect.cursor()
DBSelect.execute("select * from Stock where Stock_Item = ?", self.ui.Modify_Stock_Screen_Item.currentText())
TableRow= DBSelect.fetchone()
for Field in TableRow:
    CurrentQuantity = TableRow[1]
    CurrentQuantity = int(CurrentQuantity)
    UpdatedQuantity = int(CurrentQuantity + Change)
    DBSelect.execute('update Stock set Current_Quantity = UpdatedQuantity where Stock_Item = ?', self.ui.Modify_Stock_Screen_Item.currentText())
    DBConnect.commit()
```

I get the following error:

```
DBSelect.execute('update Stock set Current_Quantity = "UpdatedQuantity" where Stock_Item = ?', self.ui.Modify_Stock_Screen_Item.currentText())
pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Comment: The fact that Access asks for 2 parameters in the error message `Too few parameters. Expected 2.` is a sign that you might have misspelled a column name in `update Stock set Current_Quantity = UpdatedQuantity where Stock_Item = ?`. Please check `Current_Quantity`, `UpdatedQuantity` and `Stock_Item`.

Comment: @stephan The column name the update command applies to is "Current_Quantity" on my access file, so it can't be that - I've also spell checked each variable in this code and double checked the data types in the Design view, and these all should enable the command to proceed. Also, I have read through the code and checked all wording/spelling at it all seems to be correct - I also quickly applied print statements to each variable after each change is made, and these also produce the right values prior to the updating of the database table.

Comment: To clarify: is `UpdatedQuantity` a column name in the `Stock` table or is it supposed to be the variable `UpdatedQuantity` that you define in the code line above the `DBSelect.execute` in the Python code (and never user)? If it is the latter, your execute should look like `DBSelect.execute('update Stock set Current_Quantity = ? where Stock_Item = ?', UpdatedQuantity, self.ui.Modify_Stock_Screen_Item.currentText())`

Comment: @stephan I updated with what you said - now this error is produced:  `DBSelect.execute('update Stock set Current_Quantity = ? where Stock_Item = ?', UpdatedQuantity, self.ui.Modify_Stock_Screen_Item.currentText())
pyodbc.Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Optional feature not implemented  (106) (SQLBindParameter)')` I'm assuming this is something up with my own Access, not the code

Comment: Tough to debug from here (especially since I don't know much about Access), but `Optional feature not implemented` in odbc often means "data type not supported  by database". So I would check what data type `self.ui.Modify_Stock_Screen_Item.currentText()` returns in your Python code and compare it to the one expected by the database.

Comment: @stephan I just resolved this issue by doing a conversion from UpdatedQuantity back to string, on the line below the addition. All the code functions as expected, and without issue. Thanks a lot for the help mate!

Comment: So the type error was with `UpdatedQuantity`. Glad it was helpful and thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the Python variable name `UpdatedQuantity` was included in the SQL command text but the database engine has no idea that such a Python variable exists or what its value might be. That variable needs to be included in the parameters that are passed to the query:

```python
sql = 'update Stock set Current_Quantity = ? where Stock_Item = ?'
params = (
    UpdatedQuantity, 
    self.ui.Modify_Stock_Screen_Item.currentText()
    )
DBSelect.execute(sql, params)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is about quotes.
Like in example below:

Good version:

```
curs.execute(f"select name, surname from employee where occupation='{param}'")
```

Bad version:

```
curs.execute(f"select name, surname from employee where occupation={param}")
```

Select or update, it doesn't matter.